# Regex not finding the beginning of a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input string: 
"winslow homer harper weekly \"sharpshooter picket duty\" original"

The following regex expression:

```
(?<ModBroadBeg>.+)(?<modBroadWord>(^| )*winslow *)(?<ModBroadEnd>.*)
```

The following regex/replace expression:

```
${ModBroadBeg}+${modBroadWord}${ModBroadEnd}
```

And the following C# code. I want to replace "winslow" with "+winslow"

```
NewKeyWordOutString = Regex.Replace(NewKeyWordOutHoldString, BuildKeywordReplaceStruct, ReplaceModBroadWord);
```

I tested this in [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/) and it works.  The above code works with homer, harper and weekly.  Leading me to believe there is a problem with "winslow" because it is the beginning of the string.  I tested in Visual Studio and if I place a space in front of "winslow" the regex works.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<ModBroadBeg>.+)(?<modBroadWord>(^| )*winslow *)(?<ModBroadEnd>.*)
```

This expression is going to match an input which has one or more characters (`.+`) followed by either zero or more starts of the input (which is impossible) or spaces (`(^| )*`) followed by `winslow` with zero or more trailing spaces (`winslow *`) followed by zero or more characters (`.*`).

Basically, this is not going to match an input that starts with `winslow`.

If you simple want to replace all instances of `winslow` with `+winslow`, then you can just use:

```
(?=winslow)
```

which uses a [zero-width positive lookahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) to match the position before `winslow`, and replace the zero-length string with `+` (which is, effectively, a way to insert content at a specific point).

If you want to match the "winslow" in `foo winslow bar` but **not** in `foowinslow bar` or `foo winslowbar`, then you can use [word boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#word-boundary-b) (`\b`) to match the beginning/end of a word, like so:

```
(?=\bwinslow\b)
```

Word boundaries are use to detect when the character on one side of the boundary is whitespace and the character on the other side is not. They also work when word is bounded by the beginning or end of input, such as `winslow foo bar` and `foo bar winslow`.

Comment: Thanks JDB.  How would i specify only the first winslow?  Or have the positive look ahead find only the first one? e.g.: "winslow homer harper weekly \"sharpshooter winslow picket duty\" original".  When I use your solution, it matches the second winslow, not the first.

Comment: @BrianDietrich I don't think that C#'s regex [Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) function allows you to only replace the first match. You can, however, use the [Match()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match(v=vs.110).aspx) function to find the first instance, which will give you the start and length of the matched string. You can use that information to get the substrings of the unmatched portion, then concatenate the string back together with the replacement text.